# How to fix "Invalid read of size 8" valgrind error for doubly linked list code?

Tags: c, valgrind, doubly-linked-list

I am currently working on a project to implement a doubly linked list with the nodes as structures that hold MP3 information. I believe I have, for the most part, correctly implemented the data structure. The issue I am having is through a feature I am trying to implement. The feature is that a user would input a name which would would be used to traverse the list to remove all nodes whose field is the same. The problem is that when I do this, valgrind tells me:

> Invalid read of size 8.

The implementation of the data structure and the clearing of memory upon exit seem to work for me as I never get any memory leaks or segmentation faults. I only dynamically allocate the struct and two fields for the node and I make sure to free the fields first, and then the node. I have also found that I only get this issue once when I call the function for the first time.

```c
//The struct
typedef struct mp3 {
        char *name;
        char *title;
        int year;
        int runtime;
        struct mp3 *next;
        struct mp3 *prev;
}mp3_t;

//The problematic function
void deleteArtist(mp3_t **head, mp3_t **tail){
        mp3_t *current = *head;
        int compareR;
        printf("Please enter the name of the artist whose information you want deleted: \n");
        char buffer[BUFFERSIZE];
        int len;

        if(fgets(buffer,BUFFERSIZE,stdin) != NULL){
                len = (int) strlen(buffer);
                buffer[len-1] = '\0';
        }
        while(current != NULL){
                compareR = strcmp(current->name, buffer);
                if(compareR == 0){
                        free(current->title);
                        free(current->name);
                        if(current->prev == NULL && current->next == NULL){
                                free(current);
                                *head = NULL;
                                *tail = NULL;
                        }

                        else if(current->prev == NULL){
                                current->next->prev = NULL;
                                *head = current->next;
                                free(current);

                        }
                        else if(current->next == NULL){
                                current->prev->next = NULL;
                                *tail = current->prev;
                                free(current);
                        }
                        else{
                                current->prev->next = current->next;
                                current->next->prev = current->prev;
                                free(current);
                        }

                }
                current = current->next;
        }
}
```

Despite valgrind telling me the error message, the program runs as I expect it to which is what confuses me the most. My first guess is that I am calling `free()` on a node which might not have all its field filled(?) Or something to do with my use of a double pointer.

Edit: Here is an example of such an error

```sh
==29909== Invalid read of size 8
==29909==    at 0x400F11: deleteArtist (in /usa/tfessara/project1/mp3)
==29909==    by 0x4011EB: main (in /usa/tfessara/project1/mp3)
==29909==  Address 0x52048d8 is 24 bytes inside a block of size 40 free'd
==29909==    at 0x4C2EDEB: free (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==29909==    by 0x400E3C: deleteArtist (in /usa/tfessara/project1/mp3)
==29909==    by 0x4011EB: main (in /usa/tfessara/project1/mp3)
==29909==  Block was alloc'd at
==29909==    at 0x4C2DB8F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==29909==    by 0x4009EC: makeNewMP3 (in /usa/tfessara/project1/mp3)
==29909==    by 0x401191: main (in /usa/tfessara/project1/mp3)
==29909==
```

Comment: Where exactly is that warning shown for?

Comment: Note the complete error message you're getting from valgrind.

Comment: Why are there no line numbers? Did you compile without `-g`? Also, where's the rest of the code?

Comment: Your loop does `free(current); ... current = current->next;`. You cannot access `current->next` after `current` has been freed.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is resolved. It was because of the free(current); ... current = current->next;. issue that -melponene pointed out. Thanks!